# Calling pretty-printer function from the base class of an AST

Tags: f#

I'm porting a C# project to F# and there's a rather large type hierarchy that represents a SQL AST. On the base type of the hierarchy, `SqlNode`, `ToString` is overridden to call a pretty printer that operates on `SqlNode`'s subtypes. Something like this:

```
type SqlNode =
    override x.ToString() = SqlPrinter.Print x

...
// a bunch of node types deriving from SqlNode
...

type SqlPrinter =
    static member Print(node: SqlNode) =
        match node with
        | :? SqlSelect -> ...
        | :? SqlInsert -> ...
        // etc.
```

How could I port this to F# without putting the formatting logic in the nodes themselves?

Comment: Why are you porting it to a class hierarchy instead of an ADT?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin By *ADT*, do you mean *Algebraic Data Type?*

Comment: Because several branches of the class hierarchy share a common subtype. For example, `SqlInsert` and `SqlUpdate` both derive from `SqlDmlQuery`. The nesting is pretty deep in some places. Porting it to an ADT would result in constructor calls like `SqlQuery(SqlDmlQuery(SqlInsert(...)))`. A bit nasty IMO.

Comment: BTW, the type of the nodes is a distraction. The issue still remains.

Comment: What's the obstacle?  You need to use `and` to define the types, since they reference each other, but other than that it seems like it should work just fine in F#.

Comment: @kvb It's a lot of types to `and` together (30+), but maybe that's the only/best option?

Comment: To define "best" you're going to have to be more precise about what you really care about (e.g. for defining an AST in F# I'd almost always use a DU, but it sounds like you don't want to do that).  I could imagine other possible implementations, but you might not like them because you have certain constraints in mind.  For example, you could have your constructors take the printing function as an argument, and then after defining `Printer.print` you could augment the type definitions with parameterless constructors (and use a signature file to hide the other constructors if desired).

Comment: @kvb Let's just assume the ADT _is_ a DU and the printing function is in a module. What are the options, given that you can't override `ToString` in an augmentation? The goal here is to make this debug-friendly from C#.

Comment: If I used a DU, I generally wouldn't override `ToString` _in that type_.  But I might then define a type that wraps the DU and which overrides `ToString` and just calls into the `print` function defined in a separate module, and you could use that wrapping type in an API that could be used nicely from F# or C#.